# Are EC2 public DNS names associated with Elastic IPs stable?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

When I spin up a machine in us-west-2 and give it an elastic IP, it gets a public DNS hostname like

```
ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

When I spin up a machine in us-east-1 and give it an elastic IP, it gets a public DNS hostname like

```
ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Why the difference?

When I reassociate an elastic IP, will the public DNS hostname be the same?

Comment: Since you got the elastic IP you should use it and not CNAME to this DNS record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you wonder for such a details, the difference is because European datacentre was established after the US one, so the Europe got the sub-domain, while the US kept the original short version to preserve the backwards compatibility and increase stability of already deployed services.

Answer (score 2):

Elastic ips' public DNS hostname always stays the same.
When you associate an elastic ip to instance, the instance's public DNS hostname changes.